# Contar quantos filhos o pai tem (Auto Relacionada)

Tags: sql-server

Tabela:

```
FilhoID INT PK,
PaiID INT FK
```

Query:

```
SELECT FilhoID, PaiID, (SELECT COUNT(PaiID) FROM tabela WHERE PaiID = FilhoID) as 'Total Filhos' FROM tabela
```

Minha duvida:

O meu `SELECT` dentro do `SELECT`, queria que ele fizesse uma contagem de quantos filhos o pai tem. Posteriormente vou fazer verificação com esse numero. (Eu posso ter invertido a questão de pai e filho, mas acredito que isso não impeça você de me ajudar)

[image: 1]]

Na coluna `Total Filhos`, gostaria que aparecesse assim

```
FilhoID    PaiID     Total Filhos
   1       null           3
   2        1             1
   3        1             0
   4        1             0
```

Ou seja para:

- FilhoID 1 -> 3 PaiID;
- FilhoID 2 -> 1 PaiID;
- FilhoID 3 -> 0 PaiID;
- FilhoID 4 -> 0 PaiID.

No C#, mando isso para uma `List`

Ficou claro? Precisam de mais algum detalhe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O importante é conseguir definir correctamente o conjunto de IDs (Filhos). Pois podem existir PaiID que não estão numa relação PaiID - PaiID. Para isso pode começar por fazer uma união das duas tabelas de forma a obter todos os IDs:

- IDs dos filhos extraidos das relações FilhoID - PaiID
- IDs dos pais que não têm pai

Depois apenas necessita de contar o número de filhos para cada PaiID, por exemplo com uma query directamente no SELECT mais externo.

```
SELECT IDs.FilhoID, 
       IDs.PaiID, 
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT FilhoID) from tabela t2 where t2.PaiID = IDs.FilhoID) AS TotalFilhos
  FROM
  (
    SELECT FilhoID, PaiID
      FROM tabela
     UNION
    SELECT t1.PaiID, NULL
      FROM tabela t1
      LEFT JOIN tabela t2
        ON t2.FilhoID = t1.PaiID
     WHERE t2.FilhoID IS NULL
  ) IDs
 ORDER BY 1
```

Para uma tabela com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
PaiID   FilhoID
1       2
1       3
1       4
2       5
```

Este será o resultado:

```
FilhoID     PaiID   TotalFilhos
1           NULL    3
2           1       1
3           1       0
4           1       0
5           2       0
```

Comment: Deu certo, so me ajuda em mais uma coisinha, nessa mesma query eu tenho um join, como que eu faço com essa sua resposta?

Comment: Por favor actualize a pergunta com os detalhes (join) que eu actualizo a resposta.

Comment: consegui fazer, coloquei nas 2 querys dentro do FROM ( )

Comment: @LeoHenrique, Perfeito!